# React Native - Invariant Violation on ToolbarAndroid

Tags: typescript, react-native

I tried using ToolbarAndroid component but I always get this error message

[image]

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, ToolbarAndroid } from 'react-native';

public render() {
return (
  <View>
    <ToolbarAndroid 
      style={styles.toolbar}
      title="test"
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.navigation.openDrawer}>
        <Icon name={'md-menu'} size={30} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    height: 56,
}});
```

but It works fine if I remove the ToolbarAndroid component. I tried copy pasting other codes but got same error. I'm using `"react-native": "0.61.5"` version.

Comment: try removing the style property of toolbar android

Comment: @GauravRoy I tried but doesn't work.

Comment: check this its working https://snack.expo.io/rkbCGxtCr

Comment: Its only works on web but try looking on android its got the same error https://prnt.sc/qd27eg

Comment: Oh wait.. They removed it on 0.61 :3 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26591

Comment: oh okay :P lol ,t hat was unseen'